# How to initialize auto-type array of multiple types objects

Tags: c++, arrays, auto

I need to initialize an array with arguments of a `tuple`. So I tried to set it like this :

```
auto average_intensity(Ts&&... args)
{
    auto pixels[] = {args... };
    // [...]
}
```

But I get the following error :

> ‘pixels’ declared as array of ‘auto’   auto pixels[] = {args... };

How can I fix this ?

Here is the full code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>


using namespace std;

struct gray_pixel{
  uint8_t gray;
  auto intensity(){
      return gray - 127;  
  }
};


struct rgb_pixel{
  float red, green, blue;
  auto intensity(){
      return (red - 127 + green -127 + blue - 127) * 255 / 3;  
  }
};


template<typename T>
auto intensity(T pixel){
    return pixel.intensity();
}
//find the average intensity of multiple pixels from different types (gray_pixel or rgb_pixel)
template <typename... Ts>
auto average_intensity(Ts&&... args)
{
    auto pixels[] = {args...};

    auto sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(auto pixel : pixels){
        sum +=intensity(pixel);
        count++;
    }
    return sum/count;
}


int main()
{

    gray_pixel pixel_gray = {255};
    rgb_pixel pixel_rgb = {0,0,250};

    cout << "sizeof(pixel_gray): " << sizeof(pixel_gray) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(pixel_rgb): " << sizeof(pixel_rgb) << endl;

    cout << "intensity(pixel_gray): " << intensity(pixel_gray) << endl;
    cout << "intensity(pixel_rgb): " << intensity(pixel_rgb) << endl;

    cout << "average_intensity(pixel_gray, pixel_rgb): " << average_intensity(pixel_gray, pixel_rgb) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the actual type here would be `std::remove_reference_t<Ts>`

Comment: your understanding of auto might be wrong... https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-8-the-auto-keyword/

Comment: What compiler? What version of C++?

Comment: An array of multiple object types is a `tuple`. Of which type are your objects? As you call them `pixels` I'd assume them to be of same type.You should give a concrete example.

Comment: @florestan No they aren't, the purpose of average_intensity is to calculate intensity of multiple pixels of different types. I added the full code

Comment: Ok, so in this case you need a tuple. I've updated my answer. However, as the original code contains many "mistakes" such as missing `const` qualifiers or wrong function signature for the `intensity` function, I'd suggest you study the basics of c++ first as working with heterogenous containers like `tuples` is quite an advanced topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tuple instead of an array. However then you can't use a for loop but you have to exploit compile-time methods as the fold expression in the code below:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct gray_pixel  {
    uint8_t gray;
    auto intensity() const {
        return gray - 127;
    }
};


struct rgb_pixel{
    float red, green, blue;
    auto intensity() const {
        return (red - 127 + green -127 + blue - 127) * 255 / 3;
    }
};


template<typename T>
auto intensity(const T& pixel){
    return pixel.intensity();
}
//find the average intensity of multiple pixels from different types (gray_pixel or rgb_pixel)
template <typename... Ts>
auto average_intensity(Ts&&... args)
{

    // you actually don't need this here, but I leave it
    // to clarify how to capture the args in a tuple.    
    // you can use std::apply to perform calculations on the elements
    auto tup = std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);

    const float count = sizeof...(Ts);

    // a lambda that gets the intensity of a single pixel
    auto get_intensity = [](auto&& pix) {
        return static_cast<float>(std::forward<decltype(pix)>(pix).intensity());
    };
    // fold expression to sum all the intensities of the args
    auto sum = (get_intensity(args) + ...);
    return sum/count;
}


int main()
{

    gray_pixel pixel_gray = {255};
    rgb_pixel pixel_rgb = {255,127,127};

    cout << "sizeof(pixel_gray): " << sizeof(pixel_gray) << endl;
    cout << "sizeof(pixel_rgb): " << sizeof(pixel_rgb) << endl;

    cout << "intensity(pixel_gray): " << intensity(pixel_gray) << endl;
    cout << "intensity(pixel_rgb): " << intensity(pixel_rgb) << endl;

    cout << "average_intensity(pixel_gray, pixel_rgb): " << average_intensity(pixel_gray, pixel_rgb) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This was the answer to the original question:

You could try it like this:

If all of your `Ts` are of the same type, you can drop the `std::common_type` and use the type of the first element instead.
Also I'd suggest to use `std::array` instead of a C-style array.

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template<typename... Ts>
auto average_intensity(Ts&&... ts) {

    using Auto = std::common_type_t <std::decay_t<Ts>...>;

    std::array<Auto, sizeof...(Ts)> pixels {std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};

    // or if you really want an C-style array
    Auto pixels[]{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};

}
```

Comment: Yeah youre right, that was just for testing. I'll fix it as  soon as I'm back in my desktop. Android APP doesn't allow proper editing :(

Comment: Fixed the answer. I literally never use C-arrays...

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that Ts can have different types. I updated my question

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works nicely. It is advanced for me indeed, i still have a lot to learn